# iOS two rounded overlying rectangles

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'd like to put a rounded box inside the other one, like this:

[image]

As you can see, the right edge is cut off, but I can't understand why.

This is the code I'm using:

```
    let underButton = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner.allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0))
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = underButton.bounds
    gradient.colors = [UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1).cgColor, UIColor(red: 200.0/255.0, green: 200.0/255.0, blue: 200.0/255.0, alpha: 1).cgColor]
    let shapeMask = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeMask.path = underButton.cgPath
    gradient.mask = shapeMask
    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at:0)
    
    let overRect = CGRect(x : rect.origin.x + 3, y : rect.origin.y, width : rect.size.width - 12.0, height: rect.size.height - 6.0)
    let overButton = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: overRect, byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner.allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0))
    let gradient2 = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient2.frame = overButton.bounds
    gradient2.colors = [UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1).cgColor, UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1).cgColor]
    let shapeMask2 = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeMask2.path = overButton.cgPath
    gradient2.mask = shapeMask2
    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient2, at:1)
```

Can someone help me to understand where I'm wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sure, because that is the right boundary of the gradient layer. The mask shape rounded rect is wider than the gradient layer. You cannot draw outside of your own bounds, so the shape is cut off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no sense to set the `frame` of something in terms of anything but its superview / superlayer, so the line `gradient.frame = underButton.bounds` is wrong both times. You want both gradient frames to be `self.layer.bounds` because that will be their superlayer.

Then just shift the inner button over so that it is centered, with `x : rect.origin.x + 6` instead of 3, and you're done.

(I'm guess you also want to add 3 to the y origin but that's just a guess. You did not show an image of the desired output.)